# How can I execute an unexported module function in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have a module that I'm working on that only exports a few of its functions.

For testing, I sometimes want to execute unexported module functions (or read `$script:` variables, etc).

How can I do that (without exporting those functions)?

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Comment: Instead of using the `Import-Module` machinery, just dot-source the file instead (`. $filename`).

Comment: To run an unexported function: `& (Get-Module 'YourModule') { YourUnexportedFunction }`. I don't make this an answer as this has propably been answered before.

Comment: Feel free to dupe this question if it has---I couldn't find anything when I did a search. @zett42 you sure you don't want to write that as an answer?